# How to use ip rule and ip route commands for IPv6 addresses?

Tags: linux, networking, router, ip, routing

For IPv4 we use:

```
ip rule add from (ipv4 address) table 60
ip route -net (ipv4 address) mask (ipv4 mask) (interface number)
```

How do I use the `ip rule` and `ip route` commands for IPv6 addresses?

Comment: What happens when you use the exact same syntax for an IPv6 rule and route, but with the `-6` option or `-family inet6` where appropriate?

Comment: `man ip` would tell you all you need.

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent IPv6 versions require you to use "-6":

Add rule:

```
ip -6 rule add from 1234:5678:9abc:def0::/64 table 60
```

Add route:

```
ip -6 route 1234:5678:9abc:def0::/64 dev eth0
```